# Обучающий материал по базе данных

Tags: java, android

Калькулятор должен брать ставки из тарифов и подставлять в зависимости от задачи в калькулятор и считать стоимость.

Как реализовать экран, так как тарифы транспортной компании и направления по 100-200шт, как мне сделать? нужно создать базу данных или что?

Хотел делать отдельные активити для каждого тарифа но это перебор.

Подкиньте материалов как реализовать это, я хотя бы поизучаю материал связанный с этим.

Comment: Не понятно что надо. Если надо много экранов различных можно воспользоваться например Navigation Architecture Component По бд на андроид материала полно.

Comment: я просто не знаю как реализовать данный способ. Есть транспортная компания, есть калькулятор и есть ставки на перевозку.
Мне нужно что бы калькулятор брал ставку зависимости от города отправки и получения и подставлял в калькулятор, и здесь проблема я не знаю как это реализовать.
Так как тарифов 100+ шт отдельные ставки я сделать не могу, и вот хотел бы узнать это делается через базу данных? можно ли как то заставить джава логику брать тарифы строго с сайта?

Comment: Ну если вы планируете онлайн обращаться к сайту к бд то это одно, я не знаю погуглите например так: Могу ли я подключится к бд на сайте с android приложения Если н сайте есть апи с выдачей нужного то тут в помощь Retrofit Если оффлайн сами все заполнять будете то просто по бд погуглте:sqlite android startandroid и заполняйте бд сами например с помощью SQLiteStudio

Comment: Спасибо, начну изучать это, а то не знал в какую сторону двигаться что бы не создавать кучу активити)